# ¿Cuándo adquirió la locución adverbial "en la vida" un sentido negativo?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, historia, adverbios, locuciones

En español es de uso común la expresión "en la vida" con sentido negativo:

> En la vida me casaré contigo.

Lo que me fascina de esa frase es que *a priori* no parece contener ninguna palabra negativa. Si nos atenemos al sentido estrictamente literal, parece que está diciendo que en algún momento de la vida se casará con la otra persona. Sin embargo, sabemos perfectamente que la frase dice todo lo contrario, ya que según la RAE, *[en la vida](http://dle.rae.es/?id=blw7uSa)* significa "nunca".

Me puse a investigar pensando en que sería una construcción reciente, abreviada de expresiones como "nunca en la vida", pero mi sorpresa vino cuando vi que en el diccionario de autoridades (tomo S-Z, 1739) ya viene la expresión:

> **En mi vida**, ò **en la vida**. Modo adverbial, que vale Nunca, ò en ningun tiempo. Usase para explicar la incapacidad, ò suma dificultad de conseguir alguna cosa. Lat. *Nunquam*.

Otros diccionarios anteriores (según el [NTLLE](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/nuevo-tesoro-lexicografico)) no llegan a recoger esta expresión. No sé si por no ser demasiado exhaustivos o por no existir ya tan atrás en el tiempo.

Así pues, la expresión es mucho más antigua de lo que pensaba. ¿Hasta cuándo se remonta? Buscando en el CORDE he encontrado las siguientes frases:

> "Y pues no te puedo servir, no quiero enojarte ni más te hablar, salvo pedirte, en galardón de mi fe, que me des las manos que te bese, porque desta gloria goze en la muerte, pues **en la vida** no pude ni tú me dexaste."
>
> "Dixiste que quisieras que rogasse por tu muerte, porque en ella de nuestra amistad gozássemos, pues **en la vida** no podimos [...]"

Ambas frases son de 1496, y ambas llevan el "no" en el verbo, mas no sé si frases así podrían constituir el germen de lo que sería la expresión actual.

Comment: Es curioso, ese *no* implicito en *en la vida*, se esfuma si usamos *jamás* para la negativa y vuelve a recuperar su significado habitual: *Jamás en la vida me casaré contigo*. Aquí la negativa la pone *jamás* y *en la vida* pasa a ser solo un período de tiempo

Comment: En el CORDE buscando  _jamás en mi vida_ aparece ya en 1511 y si ponemos  _jamás en la vida_ la primera coincidencia es de 100 años antes: 1411 - 1412 .

Comment: @blonfu se podría pensar que simplemente en algún momento se eliminó _jamás_ de la frase, manteniendo el mismo sentido de cuando sí lo llevaba.

Comment: Sigo mirando ejemplos, sin el _jamás_ hay demasiadas coincidencias pero he encontrado algunas referencias entre 1500-1600 que usan la expresión "que en mi vida he visto" que puede sustituirse por _nunca_. Por ejemplo "el azémila cargada del más singular vino que en mi vida aya visto."  _(He borrado una parte del comentario porque me estaba liando de tantas vueltas que le he dado a la frase)_

Comment: Yo miraría en latín clásico, es más que posible que ya nos viniera dada. Para mí es también obvio que se trata de una abreviatura mediante supresión de la partícula negativa.

Comment: Es muy usual el uso del posesivo: En mi vida me casaré con ella / En su vida haría una cosa así. (significado: nunca en la vida)

Cabe asimismo agregar que esa construcción siempre aparece al inicio, como para reforzar su valor enfático. De hecho, en la lengua oral se suele acentuar.

Comment: **En la vida mataría yo a alguien** no suena negativo. La premisa de que **en la vida es negativo** creo que es incorrecta.

Comment: @DGaleano Pues yo entiendo "en la vida mataría yo a alguien" como "yo nunca mataría a alguien", que es negativa. Negativa en el sentido de que no lo vas a hacer nunca.

Comment: @Carlos Si, he leido muchas veces in la negativa y también me he preguntado por qué. A lo mejor son textos de España no son de América latina

Comment: Es un ejemplo del ciclo de Jesperson, como [en absoluto](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/cómo-ha-llegado-en-absoluto-a-significar-de-ningún-modo).

Answer (score 7):

Mi teoría es que la interpretación negativa de "En la vida" (uso mayúscula porque cuanto tiene sentido negativo siempre se utiliza al inicio de la oración) siempre existió.

Entonces, más que preguntar cuándo la frase adquirió sentido negativo -- y suponiendo que mi teoría sea verdadera, como espero poder demostrar más abajo -- sería interesante explicar cuándo la frase tiene sentido negativo de modo que los hablantes nativos y sobre todo los estudiantes de la lengua entiendan cómo funciona.

Mi teoría es que "En la vida" (y muy a menudo la misma frase pero con el posesivo correspondiente al sujeto: En mi vida, En tu vida, En su vida) siempre ha tenido sentido negativo y ha convivido con la misma frase en negativo (si es que ésta es posible) cuando se cumplen ciertas condiciones, a saber:

- Como ya dije, debe tener posición inicial. De lo contrario, para conferir sentido negativo será necesario el "no": No lo voy a obedecer en mi vida. (Pero: En mi vida lo voy a obedecer)
- Uso de un pasado que denote una experiencia de toda la vida, o uso de un futuro, subjuntivo o potencial para indicar la no realización de la acción:

  - PASADO: En mi vida sentí ese odio. (Para quienes hablen inglés, se utilizaría el "present perfect" típico de las experiencias de vida: Never in my life/Never before **have I experienced** that/such a feeling of hatred.)
  - FUTURO: En su vida se casará con él.
  - SUBJUNTIVO: En la vida quisiera pasar por esa experiencia.
  - POTENCIAL: En tu vida rechazarías esa oferta.
- Uso de un artículo o adjetivo/pronombre indefinido (un, algún, alguien, etc.)  que complete su sentido negativo con el uso de la frase en cuestión y/o de una palabra de índole comparativa que permita oponer dos realidades:

  - En la vida vi **algo así.** (Nunca vi nada como lo que veo ahora.) PERO: En la vida no tuve un solo respiro. ("solo" impide prescindir de "no".)
  - En su vida vio **tanto** dinero junto. (Es la primera vez que vio tanto dinero junto; antes, nunca había visto tanto.)
- Ausencia de otros circunstanciales de tiempo: En la vida vi eso (negativo) PERO En la vida vi eso en tres oportunidades (afirmativo).

Nótese que ninguna de las oraciones de mis ejemplos precedentes resiste el uso expreso del negativo. El "no" sólo aparecerá cuando "en la/mi/tu/su vida" aparezca al final.

Respecto de los ejemplos de la pregunta: "... en la vida no pude ni tú me dexaste (en español actual: dejaste) " y "en la vida no podimos (en español actual: pudimos"), el "no" puede omitirse sólo en el segundo caso, pues en el primero hay coordinación con "ni". Creo que sólo el pasado -- en especial cuando no está acompañado por los otros elementos que mencioné -- permite el verbo en afirmativo o negativo con la frase inicial (con sentido negativo) "En la vida".

Comment: Entiendo entonces, resumiendo un poco tu respuesta, que "En la vida" ha tenido siempre un sentido negativo, solo que debe ir acompañado de determinadas palabras. Así, "en la vida tuve un respiro" se podría interpretar de forma literal, mientras que "en la vida tuve respiro alguno" ya sí es negativa. Por tanto, mis ejemplos ("en la vida no pude/pudimos") no son válidos porque de eliminar el "no" su sentido cambiaría. Es interesante, puesto que ya hay un comentario que propone que igual tendríamos que remontarnos al latín para averiguar el origen.

Comment: La oración "En la vida tuve un respiro" es ambigua. Si la decimos enfáticamente, será negativa. No obstante, su interpretación literal (afirmativa: tener un solo respiro en la vida) es bastante improbable. Claramente, con "alguno" se vuelve negativa. Respecto de tus ejemplos, si decimos "En la vida pude obtener eso" es negativa, pero si decimos "En la vida pude obtener eso y mucho más" ya es afirmativa. "En la vida no pude conseguir lo que quería"  es negativa, mientras que "En la vida pude conseguir lo que quería" es ambigua.

Comment: Sigo aquí: Tu pregunta fue muy interesante, pero como traté de expresar en mi respuesta, más que remontarnos a su origen, creo que lo más jugoso de la cuestión radica en analizar distintos ejemplos y su significado y uso actual, a fin de encontrar las reglas que rigen el empleo de la frase con uno u otro sentido.