# Is you is or is you ain't negative?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

I wonder about the translation of this passage from Tom Sawyer:

> Earnest, Huck -- just as earnest as ever I was in my life. Will you go in there with me and help get it out?
>
> — En serio, Huck. En mi vida hablé más en serio. ¿Quieres venir a la cueva y ayudarme a sacarlo?

It seems to me that maybe "En mi vida no hablé más en serio" instead. Or perhaps "No hablé en mi vida más en serio" or something similar.

Am I wrong? It seems to be saying, "I have spoken more seriously in my life" when it should be more like, "I have never spoken more seriously in my life."

Comment: When used at the beginning of a sentence "en mi vida" has a negative sense. You can read more about it here: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18442/cu%C3%A1ndo-adquiri%C3%B3-la-locuci%C3%B3n-adverbial-en-la-vida-un-sentido-negativo and here: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19967/how-can-this-sentence-have-a-negative-meaning-without-a-no

Comment: That sentence has an implicit "never" in it. **(nunca) en mi vida hablé más en serio.**