# ¿Cómo ha llegado "en absoluto" a significar de ningún modo?

Tags: etimología, significado, historia

Ejemplo de "La Fórmula Secreta":

> —Yo... también hago experimentos...
>   —¿Te estás burlando de mí,
>   muchacho?
>   —En absoluto. Es verdad. Siempre he sentido pasión por la
>   química, pero a los chicos de mi clase no les interesan esas cosas,
>   mis padres no me toman en serio, entonces pensé que aquí con usted...

¿Cuándo y cómo ha occurido la transformación del sentido literal ["resuelta y terminante"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0CY07hD) al significado aparentemente contrario o negativo?

Comment: Es interesante. Me da la impresión de que su función es figurativa.

Comment: En [esta otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18442/12637) tratamos un tema similar con la locución "en la vida".

Answer (score 1):

En línea con el atinado paralelo que Carlos Alejo ha hecho con [esta otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18442/cu%C3%A1ndo-adquiri%C3%B3-la-locuci%C3%B3n-adverbial-en-la-vida-un-sentido-negativo) que yo mismo respondí hace un tiempo, no creo que haya habido una transformación por la cual "en absoluto" haya adquirido un sentido negativo. En realidad, la acepción correcta de esa locución adverbial es la segunda que menciona el DRAE:

```
En absoluto: loc. adv. No, de ningún modo.
```

La principal diferencia que observo con la frase "en la vida" es que "en absoluto" sólo es negativa *per se* cuando se utiliza sola (por lo menos, en el habla corriente). De lo contrario, siempre estará acompañada por un negativo:

- **No** me estoy burlando **en absoluto**.