# Uso de la expresión de forma alguna

Tags: expresiones, significado

En la siguiente oración: "O bien disciplinas a tus hijos, o bien traspasas esa responsabilidad al cruel e insensible mundo, pero la motivación para hacer hacer esto último de forma alguna debe confundirse con el amor"

El uso de la expresión "de forma alguna" tendría el significado de "de ninguna forma"? Para mí tiene más sentido en este caso, pero si se acepta el significado "de forma alguna" como "de alguna forma", el sentido cambia totalmente. Es posible que se pueda usar en el primer sentido? Lo que quiero decir, es que para mí es más lógico que al autor quiera decir que no debemos confundir lo "último" con amor, pero la expresión da a entender lo contrario. O quizás se deba a un error de traducción.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si bien tanto la [RAE](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/997047647059005440?lang=en) como [Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/alguno/) (que cita el DPD) se refieren al **valor negativo de "alguno" cuando aparece despúes del sustantivo**, en ambos casos se citan ejemplos con verbos en negativo, e incluso Fundéu dice que el verbo DEBE ir en negativo:

> La expresión «en modo alguno» es normal en español con el sentido de 'de ningún modo' o 'nada': «No quiero, en modo alguno, mezclarme en este asunto» (J. M. Fajardo, «La epopeya de los locos»); «Iscam no parecía en modo alguno fatigado» (J. Torbado, «El peregrino»).

> Así, en ejemplos como «Canarias asegura que no pedirá rescate alguno» o «Por tanto, el tiempo no significará obstáculo alguno», *alguno* toma un sentido negativo y se comporta como un sinónimo de *ninguno*. Como puede verse, el verbo aparece también, necesariamente, en forma negativa.
> Estas frases equivalen en realidad a «Canarias asegura que no pedirá  rescate ninguno» y «Por tanto, el tiempo no significará obstáculo ninguno».

Lo que ambas fuentes omiten es que, **cuando el verbo aparece después, adopta la forma afirmativa**: toda la negatividad la expresa la frase "en modo alguno", "de modo alguno", "de manera alguna", "de forma alguna":

- Esto último **de forma alguna debe** confundirse con el amor (= Esto último **de ninguna forma debe** confundirse con el amor = Esto **no debe de forma alguna/de ninguna forma** confundirse con el amor.)

Contrariamente a lo que dice la otra respuesta respecto de la agramaticalidad de la oración, pueden encontrarse en google books decenas (por no decir cientos) de buenos ejemplos de oraciones con *en modo alguno puede, en modo alguno debe*, etc.

En [este sitio](http://www.hispanoteca.eu/Foro/ARCHIVO-Foro/Alguno%20de%20ustedes%20o%20alguien%20de%20estedes.htm), puede leerse:

> *alguno* se aplica indeterminadamente a una o varias personas o cosas respecto a otras, en oposición a *ninguno*: *¿Ha venido alguno? Algunos hay que no se sorprenden por nada.*
> Pospuesto al sustantivo, equivale a *ningún* o *ninguna*: *No hay razón alguna para que hables así. **En modo alguno podemos** admitir eso. **En parte alguna he visto** cosa igual.*

Además, en el libro "Construcción e interpretación de discursos y enunciados: los marcadores" de Manuel Martí Sánchez, se puede encontrar esta página sobre "operadores de negación". Véase que, en sintonía con los ejemplos marcados en negritas en el párrafo anterior, este otro autor también afirma que "no" puede desaparecer cuando esos operadores (incluido ["en mi vida"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18442/cu%C3%A1ndo-adquiri%C3%B3-la-locuci%C3%B3n-adverbial-en-la-vida-un-sentido-negativo)) aparecen antes:

[image: Negación]

Answer (score 1):

Correcto: la expresión significa lo mismo que **de ninguna forma**.

En mi opinión la frase del traductor podría mejorarse agregándole un sentido de negación previo.  Por ejemplo, fíjate cúanto más claro resulta la expresión cuando va precedida de una negación (con sólo el mínimo agregado de la palabra «no» y el uso del verbo por delante)

> *O bien disciplinas a tus hijos, o bien traspasas esa responsabilidad al cruel e insensible mundo, pero la motivación para hacer hacer esto último **no debe de forma alguna** confundirse con el amor*

Es una cuestión de gusto estilístico, independiénte de la gramática  para aportar a una mejor comprensión. Algo que puede resultar más natural, como decir:

> *No* renunciaremos *de forma alguna* al programa de mejoras que nos propusimos seguir.

Comment: No hay motivo para que el verbo DEBA preceder la frase "de forma alguna". La flexibilidad del idioma permite que aparezca después. La oración, tal como está, está en perfecto castellano, no es una mala traducción y EN MODO ALGUNO ES confusa.

Comment: Si, estoy de acuerdo con la flexibilidad del idioma, pero el punto mío es demostrar el prinqipio de negación previo que hace falta, y esa sola inversión no requiere mayores cambios para corregirla

Comment: No existe tal principio. Puede ser un criterio personal tuyo, pero no es un criterio de la lengua. No es necesaria ninguna corrección. La oración está perfectamente escrita tal como está.

Comment: Con una simple búsqueda en google books verás cómo funcionan las oraciones que contienen "en modo alguno puede/n", "de forma alguna debe/n", etc. Su sentido es claramente negativo y presciden del "no".

Comment: Bien, gracias @Gustavson, acomodé el texto para reflejar mi preferencia estilística